# Reset a ddslick json dropdown to its initial state

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using ddslick (jquery plugin) to create two json dropdowns on my page:

```
var DataComms = [
     {
           text: "7000C",
           value: 1,
           selected: false,
           imageSrc: "images/7000C.jpg"
     },
     {
           text: "6000",
           value: 2,
           selected: false,
           imageSrc: "images/6000.jpg"
     },
     {
           text: "5000",
           value: 3,
           selected: false,
           imageSrc: "images/6900.jpg"
     }
];

var DataEquip = [
     {
           text: "PMD",
           value: 1,
           selected: false,
           imageSrc: "images/PMD.jpg"
      },
      {
           text: "SD",
           value: 4,
           selected: false,
           imageSrc: "images/sd.jpg"
      }
];

$('#DropdownComms').ddslick({
    data:DataComms,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Communicators",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(data){
         //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
$('#DropdownOtherEquip').ddslick({
    data:DataOtherEquip,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Other Equipment",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
    //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

I'm trying to find a way that when any selection is made from one of the dropdowns, the onSelected function should 'reset' the other dropdown back to its initial state (showing their original 'selectText'. Currently, if I make a selection in dropdown 1, then make a selection from dropdown 2, dropdown 1 still shows the selection I had made in it.

I've tried $('#DropdownComms').ddslick('close'); which does not work.
I've also tried $('#DropdownComms').ddslick('select', {index: 0}); and that does not work either.

Any ideas on how to reset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](http://ddslickremablized.remabledesigns.com/) added the static text functionality on top of ddSlick:

"Keep main select the same instead of changing it when an element is selected."

Comment: This plugin does the trick though I had to remove `position:absolute` from `.dd-options li a` in css to make it work.